# Ideally how many functions should be there in a function app

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-functions

As per the new template in Visual Studio 2017 prev 2, all function in a function app do share dependencies. Any custom business code/library added will be available to all other functions in a function app. 
There is a problem here that it is will give monolithic design a chance to sneak in. And any change in a function would require entire set of function to be redeployed.

Another design can be to keep the function app as thin as possible (if possible one function per function app in my opinion). This would segregate the code and dependencies of each function, but on the flip side, I would bring a deployment/maintainability nightmare.

Is there any design guideline to be followed which could balance maintainability hassle and help achieving micro service design goal ?

Comment: That's your trade-off to make ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you how much you want to group together vs be separate on their own. You can also have all your functions in 1 project in Visual Studio then deploy it to N number of function apps, then you can specify which functions a given function app should run in your `host.json`. Check the functions property in here https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json

Note that the Portal UI doesn't handle that correctly now, so you may get odd errors if you go in the portal. Tracked here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/1428